How do I determine the ID of a OneDrive item given its path using the Microsoft.Graph PowerShell module?
I want to determine the item ID of a OneDrive file given its path. I need that to invoke Get-MgDriveItemVersion:
Get-MgDriveItemVersion -DriveId $drive.id -DriveItemId '6C0F5F708F464F30!1690733'
I've obtained the drive ID using $drive = Get-MgDrive, but how do I get the DriveItemId from the item's path within the (consumer) OneDrive tree?

TL;DR here's how to determine the item ID given the path (in $OneDrivePath):
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "Files.Read.All" -NoWelcome

$drive = Get-MgDrive

$id=(Invoke-MgGraphRequest -Uri ("v1.0/me/drive/root:" + $OneDrivePath)).id

The long answer is that the Microsoft.Graph module doesn't currently directly support this operation, this is discussed, among other places, at https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-powershell/issues/813#issuecomment-1123009518
